# Cannot find function addEventListener while using php webdriver and selenium

Tags: php, facebook, selenium, automated-tests

I have only written the webdriver for three weeks. And I encounter a problem about finding addEventListener.

I use selenium standalone server, and php framework developed by facebook.

What i want is to run a headless webdriver.

There is a part of my code, below.

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default
$capabilities = array(
    Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'htmlunit',
    Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType::JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED => true,
);
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
$window = new WebDriverDimension(1024, 768);
$driver->manage()->window()->setSize($window);
```

And there is the error message

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function addEventListener in object [object HTMLDocument]. (https://www.grb.gov.tw/resource/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js#2)
Build info: version: '2.50.1', revision: 'd7fc91b', time: '2016-01-29 19:08:26'
System info: host: 'N/A', ip: 'N/A', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_75'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:554)
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.get(HtmlUnitDriver.java:530)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:103)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.get(EventFiringWebDriver.java:163)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ChangeUrl.call(ChangeUrl.java:40)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.ChangeUrl.call(ChangeUrl.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Because of some reasons, i can't update the java version to 1.8 for the latest version of selenium, and the version of selenium i used is 2.50.1.
I have found some resource about how to solve this, like assigning a higher browser version to htmlunitdriver. like this

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
```

But i have no idea how to do that under the facebook php framework. Am I bound by the framework?

Thank u for watching, and if there is a duplicate question, i am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, i solved this problem by compiling the latest htmlunit jar files into the selenium standalone server.

when opening the standalone server, using this command, `java -Djava.ext.dirs=./lib -jar /selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar`, instead of `java selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar`

the lib is a folder which contains the latest htmlunit jar files

you can download from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlunit/)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with Selenium Webdriver 2.15 (the newest version I could use due to a requirement to run with Java 1.6). I resolved it by subclassing HtmlUnitDriver and overriding the modifyWebClient method based on tips from the HtmlUnit FAQ (http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html):

```
@Override
protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    client.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
    return client;
}
```

I believe it's the first line that eliminated the exceptions, but I didn't test both ways.